# Can you have an image as a radioButton choice in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to use Shiny as an assessment tool for multiple choice items. As such, in some cases I would like to have an image as a choice. Instead, the raw HTML is shown. Can this be done in Shiny?

```
library(shiny)

choices <- c('\\( e^{i \\pi} + 1 = 0 \\)' = 'equation',
             '<img src="Rlogo.png">' = 'logo')

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
    withMathJax(),
    img(src='Rlogo.png'),
    fluidRow(column(width=12,
        radioButtons('test', 'Radio buttons with MathJax choices',
                     choices = choices, inline = TRUE),
        br(),
        h3(textOutput('selected'))
    ))
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    output$selected <- renderText({
        paste0('You selected the ', input$test)
    })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

You will have to put the R logo in the `www` directory where you place this `app.r` script. Here is a direct link to the logo: http://i1.wp.com/www.r-bloggers.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Rlogo.png?resize=300%2C263

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `img` is not displayed  in the radio buttons because the names are held in `span` and generated using `tags$span` so all HTML is escaped.

If you only have to do this once, you can copy the output of `radioButtons('test', 'Radio buttons with MathJax choices', choices = choices, inline = TRUE)`, place it in a `tags$div`, and add the image:

```
      fluidRow(column(width=12,
                        tags$div(HTML('<div id="test" class="form-group shiny-input-radiogroup shiny-input-container shiny-input-container-inline">
  <label class="control-label" for="test">Radio buttons with MathJax choices</label>
                                      <div class="shiny-options-group">
                                      <label class="radio-inline">
                                      <input type="radio" name="test" value="equation" checked="checked"/>
                                      <span>\\( e^{i \\pi} + 1 = 0 \\)</span>
                                      </label>
                                      <label class="radio-inline">
                                      <input type="radio" name="test" value="logo"/>
                                      <span><img src="http://i1.wp.com/www.r-bloggers.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Rlogo.png?resize=300%2C263"/></span>
                                      </label>
                                      </div>
                                      </div> ')),
                        br(),
                        h3(textOutput('selected'))
        ))
```

If you need to do this many times, you can define a `radioButtons_withHTML` function:

```
radioButtons_withHTML <- function (inputId, label, choices, selected = NULL, inline = FALSE, 
          width = NULL) 
{
        choices <- shiny:::choicesWithNames(choices)
        selected <- if (is.null(selected)) 
                choices[[1]]
        else {
                shiny:::validateSelected(selected, choices, inputId)
        }
        if (length(selected) > 1) 
                stop("The 'selected' argument must be of length 1")
        options <- generateOptions_withHTML(inputId, choices, selected, inline, 
                                   type = "radio")
        divClass <- "form-group shiny-input-radiogroup shiny-input-container"
        if (inline) 
                divClass <- paste(divClass, "shiny-input-container-inline")
        tags$div(id = inputId, style = if (!is.null(width)) 
                paste0("width: ", validateCssUnit(width), ";"), class = divClass, 
                shiny:::controlLabel(inputId, label), options)
}

generateOptions_withHTML <- function (inputId, choices, selected, inline, type = "checkbox") 
{
        options <- mapply(choices, names(choices), FUN = function(value, 
                                                                  name) {
                inputTag <- tags$input(type = type, name = inputId, value = value)
                if (value %in% selected) 
                        inputTag$attribs$checked <- "checked"
                if (inline) {
                        tags$label(class = paste0(type, "-inline"), inputTag, 
                                   tags$span(HTML(name)))
                }
                else {
                        tags$div(class = type, tags$label(inputTag, tags$span(HTML(name))))
                }
        }, SIMPLIFY = FALSE, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
        div(class = "shiny-options-group", options)
}
```

The difference with the original one is calls `generateOptions_withHTML` to create the names of the buttons, and I added the `HTML()` function around `name` in the `tags$span` to prevent the escaping. You can put these functions in another file and use `source`.

You can then use `radioButtons_withHTML('test', 'Radio buttons with MathJax choices',choices = choices, inline = TRUE)` to create your `radioButtons`.