# R Shiny lining up radio buttons with katex

Tags: shiny, katex

Using radio buttons in Shiny to select a model.  The models are defined by formula using katex.  Is there a way to insert katex into the choices of the buttons?

I've tried [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35783446/can-you-have-an-image-as-a-radiobutton-choice-in-shiny) which isn't working with katex:

```
radioButtons_withHTML("my_model", label = h4("Choose model"),
    choices = list(
                   HTML(katex("y = (ax^\\nu + b)^{-1}")) = 1, 
                   "Exponential" = 2), 
    selected = 1)
```

Currently the formula are next to the radio buttons, which isn't lining up.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `HTML` in `choiceNames` argument as follows:

```
library(shiny)
    ui <- fluidPage(

      radioButtons("my_model", label = h4("Choose model"),
      choiceNames = list(tags$span(HTML("y = (ax<sup>&nu;</sup> + b)<sup>-1</sup>")),
                         tags$span(HTML("y = (e<sup>ax</sup> + &nu;e<sup>bx</sup>)<sup>-1</sup>"))
                         ), 
      choiceValues = c(1,2), selected = 1)

    )

    server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    })

    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

With this you get an output that looks like this:

[image]